# jQuery detect if HTML5 autoplay video plays already?

Tags: jquery, html5-video, onchange

I have a video element with a text overlay. I set the video to autoplay, but this can take some time when a user enters the site for the first time. For that case, I set up a poster image to display while the video hasn't started yet. What I want to achieve is, to hide/fade-out my video-overlay, as soon as the video starts playing.

My HTML looks like this:

```
  <div class="video-wrapper">    
      <div class="video-overlay">
         <h1>Lorem Ipsum</h1>
         <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
      </div>
      <div class="video-container">
        <video poster="img/default_player.jpg" id="bgvid" playsinline autoplay muted loop>
            <source src="vdo/vdo_original.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        </video>
      </div>
   </div>
```

Is there any possiblity to detect with jQuery if the video started playing already, or is still buffering?

something like:

```
var video = jQuery("#bgvid").getState();

if ( video.paused ) {
    jQuery(".video-overlay").show();
} 

else {
    jQuery(".video-overlay").hide();
}

return false;
```

And binding this to a change function or similar? Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: There are different ways to do that... But first Do you expect to use jQuery to trigger Play/Pause ? Like here :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34532133/check-if-a-html5-video-is-playing-using-jquery

Comment: Or use jQuery On('play')... like here : https://tomelliott.com/html-5/html-5-video-play-pause-jquery.

Comment: An advanced more compliacted case where you preload the video ... You would need a promise because of asynchronicity. So which method you choose? :)

Comment: @Bilel Thanks mate! I've chosen the second option and this works for my usecase. Once again thanks for pointing me the direction!

Comment: You are welcome ! Good luck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Bilel pointed out, there are diffent ways to do this. I've chosen the way of an "on-play-function".

which leaves me with this:

```
var videocontainer = '#bgvid';
 
jQuery(videocontainer).on('play', function() {
    jQuery('.video-overlay').fadeOut(400);
});
```

This works fine for me, because it fades away my overlay on play and is not needed later, because the video autoplays, loops and the controls are hidden.